# R ggplot2: colouring step plot depending on value

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I configure a ggplot2 step plot so that when the value being plotted is over a certain level it is one colour and when it is below that certain level it is another colour? (Ultimately I would like to specify the colours used.)

My first thought was that this would be a simple issue that only required me to add a column to my existing data frame and map this column to the aes() for geom_step(). That works to a point: I get two colours, but they overlap as shown in this image:
[image: geom_step() plot with overlapping colours]

I have searched SO for the past several hours and found many similar but not identical questions. However, despite trying a wide variety of combinations in different layers I have not been able to resolve the problem. Code follows. Any help much appreciated.

```
require(ggplot2)

tmp <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1325635200, 1325635800, 1325636400, 
1325637000, 1325637600, 1325638200, 1325638800, 1325639400, 1325640000, 
1325640600, 1325641200, 1325641800, 1325642400, 1325643000, 1325643600, 
1325644200, 1325647800, 1325648400, 1325649000, 1325649600, 1325650200, 
1325650800, 1325651400, 1325652000, 1325652600, 1325653200, 1325653800, 
1325654400, 1325655000, 1325655600, 1325656200, 1325656800), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), Close = c(739.07, 
739.86, 740.41, 741.21, 740.99, 741.69, 742.64, 741.34, 741.28, 
741.69, 741.6, 741.32, 741.95, 741.86, 741.02, 741.08, 742.08, 
742.88, 743.19, 743.18, 743.78, 743.65, 743.66, 742.78, 743.34, 
742.81, 743.31, 743.81, 742.91, 743.09, 742.47, 742.99)), .Names = c("date", 
"Close"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
prevclose <- 743
tmp$status <- as.factor(ifelse (tmp$Close> prevclose, "Above", "Below"))

ggplot() +
    geom_step(data = tmp,aes(date, Close, colour = status))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `group = 1` in `aes`:

```
# top panel
ggplot(tmp, aes(date, Close, colour = status, group = 1)) + 
  geom_step() + scale_colour_manual(values = c("pink", "green"))
```

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
# make sure that data is sorted by date
tmp2 <- arrange(tmp, date)

# add intermittent column between below/above
tmp3 <- tmp2[1, ]
for (i in seq(nrow(tmp2))[-1]) {
    if (tmp2[i-1, ]$status != tmp2[i, ]$status) {
        tmp3 <- rbind(tmp3,
                      transform(tmp2[i, ], Close = prevclose, status = tmp2[i-1, ]$status),
                      transform(tmp2[i, ], Close = prevclose))
    }
    tmp3 <- rbind(tmp3, tmp2[i, ])
}

# bottom panel
ggplot(tmp3, aes(date, Close, colour = status, group = 1)) + geom_step() +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("pink", "green"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks kohske (and hadley), the detailed answer is much appreciated. I knew there was one thing I was missing and had thought it was something to do with setting vs mapping or somesuch, but group was it...

Comment: Incidentally, I notice that using your solution, if the values for the day are all below the previous day (i.e. the status column is all "Below") then it colours the step line in the colour for "Above" rather than "Below". This is odd given that the status column values are correct - they are indeed all "Below". Some quirk related to the way ggplot handles values/breaks/labels perhaps?