# Fill the area above and below the central line in geom_step() with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the following PMI data, I would like to reproduce a plot similar to the figure below:

```
         date Eurozone.Markit.Composite.PMI France.Markit.Composite.PMI Germany.Markit.Composite.PMI
1   2022-1-31                          52.3                        52.7                         53.8
2   2022-2-28                          55.5                        55.5                         55.6
3   2022-3-31                          54.9                        56.3                         55.1
4   2022-4-30                          55.8                        57.6                         54.3
5   2022-5-31                          54.8                        57.0                         53.7
6   2022-6-30                          52.0                        52.5                         51.3
7   2022-7-31                          49.9                        51.7                         48.1
8   2022-8-31                          48.9                        50.4                         46.9
9   2022-9-30                          48.1                        51.2                         45.7
10 2022-10-31                          47.1                        50.0                         44.1
```

[image]

*Figure source: [Euro zone October PMI adds to evidence bloc is heading for recession](https://www.reuters.com/markets/europe/euro-zone-october-business-activity-takes-another-inflation-hit-pmi-2022-10-24/)*

The most important thing is how to **fill the area above and below the central line with different colors**. How to implement it in R ggplot2 `geom_step()`? Thanks.

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2022-1-31", "2022-2-28", "2022-3-31", 
"2022-4-30", "2022-5-31", "2022-6-30", "2022-7-31", "2022-8-31", 
"2022-9-30", "2022-10-31"), Eurozone.Markit.Composite.PMI = c(52.3, 
55.5, 54.9, 55.8, 54.8, 52, 49.9, 48.9, 48.1, 47.1), France.Markit.Composite.PMI = c(52.7, 
55.5, 56.3, 57.6, 57, 52.5, 51.7, 50.4, 51.2, 50), Germany.Markit.Composite.PMI = c(53.8, 
55.6, 55.1, 54.3, 53.7, 51.3, 48.1, 46.9, 45.7, 44.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

My code:

```
vlines <- c(45, 50, 55)
ggplot(df, aes(date, Eurozone.Markit.Composite.PMI, group = 1, color='blue')) + 
  geom_step() +
  # geom_ribbon() +
  # geom_line() +
  # sapply(vlines, function(xint) geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xint)))
  geom_vline(xintercept=vlines) +
  theme_bw()
```

Out:

[image]

**References:**

[R ggplot2: colouring step plot depending on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737454/r-ggplot2-colouring-step-plot-depending-on-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `geom_rect` and a bit of data wrangling you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df$date <- as.Date(df$date)

df <- df |> 
  mutate(xmax = lead(date), xmin = date, fill = Eurozone.Markit.Composite.PMI > 50)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = 50, ymax = Eurozone.Markit.Composite.PMI, fill = fill), alpha = .6) +
  geom_step(aes(y = Eurozone.Markit.Composite.PMI)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, date %in% range(date)), aes(y = Eurozone.Markit.Composite.PMI)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 50) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "lightgreen")) +
  guides(fill = "none")
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).
```

[image]